# Constraint Layout "wrap_content" with dimensionRatio child view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In ConstraintLayout version < beta5, I had layouts like this example below:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/square_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 1:1"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, versions starting beta5 have removed the MATCH_PARENT constraint for child views.

The documentation gives examples of using app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio:

> You can also use ratio if both dimensions are set to MATCH_CONSTRAINT
>   (0dp). In this case the system sets the largest dimensions the
>   satisfies all constraints and maintains the aspect ratio specified. To
>   constrain one specific side based on the dimensions of another. You
>   can pre append W," or H, to constrain the width or height
>   respectively. For example, If one dimension is constrained by two
>   targets (e.g. width is 0dp and centered on parent) you can indicate
>   which side should be constrained, by adding the letter W (for
>   constraining the width) or H (for constraining the height) in front of
>   the ratio, separated by a comma:

```
<Button android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#DimensionConstraints

This example works when the parent layout has a fixed height or `match_parent`, but not when the parent is set to `wrap_content`.

Using my code example above, if I set the ImageView width to 0dp, the parent view collapses as if it has no content.

This was an incredibly useful feature, I feel like I'm just missing something in this new version. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout v1.0.2` fixes this issue.